# Store value (strings or numbers) into an array after performing while loop

Tags: perl

I have a while loop below:

```
while (<>)
{
    my $line = $_;
    if ($line =~ m/ERROR 0x/)
    {
        $error_found +=1;
    }
}
```

After while loop finished, i will match somethings like "ERROR..." and i wanna store them into an array or list or hash. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just push the data into an array.

```
my @errors;
while (<>)
{
    my $line = $_;
    if ($line =~ m/ERROR 0x/)
    {
        push @errors, $line;
    }
}
```

Clean things up a little:

```
my @errors;
while (my $line = <>)
{
    if ($line =~ /ERROR 0x/)
    {
        push @errors, $line;
    }
}
```

Or maybe even

```
my @errors;
while (<>)
{
    if (/ERROR 0x/)
    {
        push @errors, $_;
    }
}
```

Finally, realize that `grep` would do great here:

```
my @errors = grep { /ERROR 0x/ } <>;
```

Comment: There is a typo in the third example, it sould be `$_` instead of `$line`.

Comment: @M42, Thanks to Borodin for fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
my @arr;
while (<>)
{
    my $line = $_;
    if ($line =~ m/ERROR 0x/)
    {
        push(@arr,$line) ;
    }
}

print "$_\n" for @arr;
```